# Why does foo have the same value as (foo) in this Racket macro?

Tags: macros, racket, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to understand macros inside the Racket environment. The concept intrigues me.

After writing this definition on Dr. Racket's definition window:

```
(define-syntax foo
    (lambda (stx)
      (syntax "I am foo")))
```

I used the REPL to call the following expressions:

```
> foo
"I am foo"

> (foo)
"I am foo"
```

These results surprise me. I was expecting something like a `#procedure` for the first call on *foo*.

Why (foo) and foo provide the same output?

Usually, I am pretty careful about adding parenthesis in Racket. Usually, they completely change the meaning of the expression being called. In this case, apparently, it makes no difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Usually, I am pretty careful about adding parenthesis in Racket.

Yes, you are right to be careful. It usually makes a difference.

In your case, however, it doesn't seem to make a difference, because you are creating an overly simple macro that happens to expand in the same way whether the macro is invoked as a regular transformer or as an [identifier macro](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html#%28part._.Identifier_.Macros%29).

> I was expecting something like a #procedure for the first call on foo.

I want to address this first. Macros transform your program syntactically. For example, I can write a macro `flip` that flip the operands, so that

```
(flip foo 1 (let) bar baz 2)
```

is *expanded* (not *evaluated*) to:

```
(2 baz bar (let) 1 foo)
```

Again, I want to emphasize that this is a program transformation, like how you edit the code with your editor.

Now, let's write some actual macros:

```
(define-syntax bar
  (lambda (stx)
    (cond
      [(equal? (syntax->datum stx) '(bar abc def)) #'(+ 1 1)]
      [else #'(+ 2 2)])))

(bar abc def)      ;== expands => (+ 1 1) == evaluates => 2
(bar 42 (abc) qqq) ;== expands => (+ 2 2) == evaluates => 4
(bar)              ;== expands => (+ 2 2) == evaluates => 4
```

In the above macro, it checks if the input syntax is syntactically `(bar abc def)`. If so, it transforms to `(+ 1 1)`. Otherwise, it transforms to `(+ 2 2)`.

All of these is to show you that it is unreasonable to expect a macro to result in "#procedure" (of course, unless the macro expands to a lambda), since what macro does is transforming syntax. It doesn't create a procedure.

The final mystery is what's going on with bare `foo`. Let's create a macro `baz` to understand that:

```
(define-syntax baz
  (lambda (stx)
    (cond
      [(equal? (syntax->datum stx) 'baz) #'1]
      [(equal? (syntax->datum stx) '(baz)) #'2]
      [else #'3])))

baz      ;== expands => 1
(baz)    ;== expands => 2
(baz 10) ;== expands => 3
```

It turns out that a bare identifier could also be a macro!

Now, consider your `foo`:

```
(define-syntax foo
    (lambda (stx)
      (syntax "I am foo")))
```

It's a transformation that ignores its operands, and always expands to `"I am foo"`.

So:

```
(foo 1 2 3) ;== expands => "I am foo"
(foo x y z) ;== expands => "I am foo"
(foo)       ;== expands => "I am foo"
foo         ;== expands => "I am foo"
```

Note that in most macros, we use pattern matching to extract operands. Pattern matching can raise a syntax error when the input syntax doesn't match any pattern. This, for example, allows us to create a macro that doesn't allow it to be used as an identifier macro.

```
(define-syntax food
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      ;; match when there is a parenthesis around the macro
      [(_ ...) #'1])))

(food) ;=> 1
food   ;=> food: bad syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

Moving my answer here:

This definition:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax "I am foo")))
```

binds `foo` to the syntax transformer `(λ (stx) (syntax "I am foo"))`.

When the macro `foo` is invoked, the syntax transformer is called
with an argument: the expression that invoked the macro.

Now, there are several ways of invoking a macro.
The usual one, is:  `(foo 42)` which will call the syntax transformer
with the argument `(syntax (foo 42))`. In our example the transformer
ignores its input (`stx`) and returns `(syntax "I am foo")` so
the macro call `(foo 42)` will be replaced with `"I am foo"`.

Another way of invoking a macro is as a reference: If `foo` occurs
alone, then the syntax transformer will be called with `(syntax foo)`
as argument. Since the transformer ignores the input, the the reference will
be replaced with `"I am foo"`.

The third way of invoking a syntax transformer is when `foo` is used in an
assignment as in `(set! foo 42)`. See "identifier macro" in the docs.

Tip: To check that the description above is what actually takes place, you can make the transformer print its argument.

```
(define-syntax foo
  (λ (stx)
    (displayln (syntax->datum stx))
    (syntax "I am foo")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked this very same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75177650/1724025) and after reading the great answers from @sorawee above and @soegaard [in my Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75177878/1724025) I think the easiest answer based on the above two answers is: **The macro is too simple as it expands to a constant that disregards syntax and the parentheses are removed**.

The following modified `foo` code snippet reveals the distinction, between the two invocations:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (λ (stx)
    (cond
      [(equal? (syntax->datum stx) '(foo)) (syntax "foo with parentheses")]
      [(equal? (syntax->datum stx) 'foo) (syntax "Just bare foo")]
      [else (syntax "some other foo invocation")])))
```

When run on the REPL then I get:

```
> foo
"Just bare foo"
> (foo)
"foo with parentheses"
> (foo something else)
"some other foo invocation"
>
```

Thanks again to both folks that provided the original answers.