# Why is macro expansion given a free pass at evaluation?

Tags: macros, racket

I was reading Greg Hendershott's [Fear of Macros](https://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/Transform_.html#%28part._.What_is_a_syntax_transformer_%29) and I stumbled into this code:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax "I am foo")))
```

Which seems quite innocent, but I notice that either on the REPL or as part of the source code, it's irrelevant whether I write a foo expansion with or without parentheses:

```
> foo
"I am foo"
> (foo)
"I am foo"
>
```

Which is odd, because If I enter things directly at the REPL:

```
> "I am foo"
"I am foo"
> ("I am foo")
. . application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: "I am foo"
>
```

I get an error when trying to call the string w/o parentheses because the string is already an irreducible constant.

So, the question I have is why does this happen?

So, any info would be appreciated.
Thanks

#### Research I have done so far:

I looked in the macro stepper and saw that the macro is wrapped several times by do-wrapping-module-begin, but I have no idea how that behaves.

```
(do-wrapping-module-begin
    print-result
    (define-syntax foo (λ (stx) (syntax "I am foo"))))
   (do-wrapping-module-begin print-result foo)
   (do-wrapping-module-begin print-result (foo))))
```

Comment: Since posting the original question SO mentions this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66727398/1724025, which is correct, but I think @soegaard answer below has its own value different than the other answer, so I leave the question here for other visitors.

Answer (score 2):

This definition:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax "I am foo")))
```

binds `foo` to the syntax transformer `(λ (stx) (syntax "I am foo"))`.

When the macro `foo` is invoked, the syntax transformer is called
with an argument: the expression that invoked the macro.

Now, there are several ways of invoking a macro.
The usual one, is:  `(foo 42)` which will call the syntax transformer
with the argument `(syntax (foo 42))`. In our example the transformer
ignores its input (`stx`) and returns `(syntax "I am foo")` so
the macro call `(foo 42)` will be replaced with `"I am foo"`.

Another way of invoking a macro is as a reference: If `foo` occurs
alone, then the syntax transformer will be called with `(syntax foo)`
as argument. Since the transformer ignores the input, the the reference will
be replaced with `"I am foo"`.

The third way of invoking a syntax transformer is when `foo` is used in an
assignment as in `(set! foo 42)`. See "identifier macro" in the docs.

Tip: To check that the description above is what actually takes place, you can make the transformer print its argument.

```
(define-syntax foo
  (λ (stx)
    (displayln (syntax->datum stx))
    (syntax "I am foo")))
```